# facebook analytics shows empty screen

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating facebook sdk to my project for facebook analytics.i am calling facebook sdk from my Activity. But in Developer facebook analytics overview shown blank space. please guys tell where did i made mistake.[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add your code to show where you call the sdk?

Comment: This is my code                                                                                  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  /* For maintain state of an app */

        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()

                .penaltyLog().build());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        try{
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(LoginActivity.this);

Comment: Edit your question, and add it there instead. I'm sorry I won't be able to answer your question, but maybe someone else can. And you increase your chances if you provide enough information wih your question.

Comment: I would report this as a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) if this is still not loading for you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make a mistake, there was a bug in the product that was fixed (over a year ago).